# Golang can't get data from db because of types

Tags: mongodb, go, types, go-fiber

I'm trying to get data from a MongoDB (previously saved using JS) and I unfortunately get empty `_id` and wrong format of the dates (saved as epoch).

Here's the data in MongoDB:

[image]

Here is the model I'm using in my Go code

[image]

and here is what I get as result

[image]

I've tried `uuid.UUID` in the ID type but I get a struct full of zeros, and when I change their types to string or byte, I get empty values.

How to get exactly the data as it's saved on the DB?

Answer (score 1):

Please check your struct tags. Replace the json tag with bson.

In Mongo you store some fields in camelCase and in Go you expect all fields to be snake case.